# How to restore "View split on right (or left)" feature

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, window

Until this morning, in Unity, I had been happily using Ctrl + Super + RightArrow (or LeftArrow) to place a window neatly on one half of my screen or the other. I'd also sometimes use the mouse to drag a window right or left, until the pointer touched the edge of the screen, and that would have the same effect.

This morning, both techniques stopped working, and the associated shortcuts disappeared from the list of shortcuts that appears when I press and hold the Super key.

In what secret corner of my system do these commands live, and what can I say to my Terminal that will bring them back to life again?

Comment: What Ubuntu version do you use?

Comment: Do you really use the Unity desktop, since you tagged with "Unity"? In current Ubuntu desktops, the hotkey is Super+arrows, so yes, you may be using Unity. Please confirm by adding the info in your question.

Comment: @vanadium Yes, indeed, this is on a laptop running Unity.